# page freezes and dont move wihle using looped js

Tags: javascript

i have written code wich should work but when i try to loop it with while or for, the page freezes.

```
$("#body").val("testing123");
var i = 0;
while (i <= 5) {
    var value = 20;
    function result(a) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
        return x[0].innerHTML;
    }
    y = result('val');
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('val').value =value;

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('play').click();

    setTimeout(function() {
        y = result('val');

    if(y == "LOSE") {
        bet = value*2;
        document.getElementById('val').value =value;
        i++;
    }
    else if(y == "WIN") {
        value = 20;
        document.getElementById('val').value =value;
        i = 5;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('val').value ='ERROR';
        value = 0;
        i = 5;
    }
    }, 2000);
    }, 2000);
    }, 7000);
}
```

i dont know what is wrong or where to catch, as I said i tried to use for and while but can't get what went wrong, whole page is frozen even with console

Comment: When do you want to break out of the loop? When you reach 5? Then you should fix to while (i < 5)

Answer (score 0):

since any adjustment to your i variable will happen only after at least 2 seconds, the while loop makes a **lot** of iterations, which result in many timeouts being registered and your single poor javascript thread be in real trouble. try re-writing this function in another manner which doesn't rely on an outer variable that is supported by timeouts.